# Can i have a property in my class that not exist in bd table using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table, in my DB, like this:

```
Table_A
Col1 nvarchar(100)
Col2 nvarchar(100)
Col3 nvarchar(100)
```

Now in my entity i have:

```
public class Table_A
{
    public string Col1 {get; set;}
    public string Col2 {get; set;}
    public string Col3 {get; set;}
    public string Col4 {get; set;}
}
```

Using EF, in some cases i need to execute a Stored Procedure that return Col1, Col2, Col3 and Col4(Col4 is a column retrive in a Left outer join with other table); the problem is that when i don't use that SP i get an error on Col4.

I am using EF Core 2.2.3 and MS SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Have you tried adding the [NotMapped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#included-and-excluded-properties) attribute?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately when i use a SP, that return Col4, the value in property is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i have a property in my class that not exist in bd table using Entity Framework?

Yes, you can use the [`NotMapped` attribute](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/notmapped-attribute)

Excerpt:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    public string Email { get; set; } 
}
```

or you can use the Fluent API [Ignore method](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ignore-method)

Excerpt:

```
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().Ignore(c => c.FullName);
    }
}
public class Contact
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    public string Email { get; set; } 
}
```

> Using EF, in some cases i need to execute a Stored Procedure that return Col1, Col2, Col3 and Col4(Col4 is a column retrive in a Left outer join with other table); the problem is that when i don't use that SP i get an error on Col4. I am using EF Core 2.2.3 and MS SQL Server 2017. Thanks.

But this begs the question, *is your actual question: can I have an optional property?* to which the answer is **no**.  The property either; always has to be mapped or never mapped.